# Trying to override a community pool template

Tags: magento-enterprise, overrides, theme

So, I am trying to override a template from an extension we have installed. This is the template location:

```
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/affiliatepluscoupon/affiliatepluscoupon.phtml
```

This is how I have gone about overriding it:

config.xml:

```
<frontend>
  <updates>
    <blizzardlabs_affiliateplusext>
      <file>blizzardlabs_affiliateplusext.xml</file>
    </blizzardlabs_affiliateplusext>
  </updates>      
</frontend>
```

Layout:

```
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/blizzardlabs_affiliateplusext.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <affiliatepluscoupon_index_index>
        <reference name="affiliatepluscoupon">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>affiliateplusext/affiliatepluscoupon.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </affiliatepluscoupon_index_index>
</layout>
```

Here is the original layout for reference:

```
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/layout/affiliatepluscoupon.xml:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <affiliateplus_default>
        <reference name="account_navigator">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="affiliatepluscoupon">
                <name>banners</name><path>affiliatepluscoupon/index/index</path><label><![CDATA[Coupon]]></label><disabled helper="affiliatepluscoupon/couponIsDisable" /><order>40</order>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </affiliateplus_default>
    <affiliatepluscoupon_index_index>
        <update handle="affiliateplus_default" />
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><styleSheet>css/magestore/affiliatepluscoupon.css</styleSheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="affiliatepluscoupon/affiliatepluscoupon" name="affiliatepluscoupon" template="affiliatepluscoupon/affiliatepluscoupon.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </affiliatepluscoupon_index_index>
</layout>
```

I feel like I have done what I should but its not picking it up. I manually flushed cache (its off anyway) / ctrl f5 and still nothing. With all these long names im probably looking at a spelling error somewhere but i can't find it. Any help?!

Comment: sort of in a rush, this link explains it, if I get time later and no one else has answered this, I will post an answer will example snippets... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753206/how-to-override-magento-template-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you will need to override the class that calls the template file.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-override-magento-admin-view-template-files-quick-and-dirty-way/

More specifically, you need to override the block that sets the template file to use...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206649/properly-override-a-admin-template-file-in-magento

However, the following link suggests it is possible without overriding any classes...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787190/how-to-override-the-admin-template-file-in-magento

Comment: Thanks for the help I was able to figure it out using these...I'll update my question with what I did later.